# Find methods with return type String

Tags: pharo, moose-technology

I try to create a query to get all methods with a specific return type. Looking at the definitions of `FAMIXMethod` and `FAMIXBehavioralEntity` I think the declaredType: is the correct method for this query on `FAMIXMethodGroup`.

I've tried to use the query:

```
self select: [ :each | each declaredType: String ]
```

But this stops with an

> error: "MessageNotUnderstood"

Answer (score 1):

`declaredType:` is a setter, so you are trying to change the declaredType, which is expected to be a `FAMIXType`. Thus the MessageNotUnderstood.

A possible approach is to get the declaredType (which is a (sub)instance of `FAMIXType`) and ask for the `smalltalkClass`. Note that declaredType may not exist.

```
self select: [ :each |
    each hasDeclaredType and: [
        each declaredType smalltalkClass isKindOf: String class ] ].
```

Maybe a simpler approach can be devised with Moose Query, but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Try `each declaredType inheritsFrom: String` instead. The `#isKindOf:` message is typically used for instances.